# Percentile function using time in Access

Tags: ms-access, timestamp, percentile, percentile-cont

I'm trying to calculate the 90th percentile of travel time for districts. I'm using MS Access.

```
SELECT DISTINCT District As District_Num, 
PERCENTILE_CONT(0.9) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Travel_Time) OVER (PARTITION BY District) AS 90th_Percentile
FROM [Incidents-J];
```

I'm getting the error message:

> "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression
>   'PERCENTILE_CONT(0.9) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Travel_Time) OVER
>   (PARTITION BY District)'

Note, travel_time is in the format of h:mm:ss. Is this the issue? Is so, what would be a way of converting it into something useful (ex 0:01:20 into 80)?

Comment: This is SQL Server sql staement. Won't work on Access except on a connection to SQL Server.

Comment: Access does not have intrinsic percentile function. Review http://www.fabalou.com/Access/Modules/percentile.asp and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30872060/quartile-percentile-in-ms-access-via-sql-with-a-group-by-when-some-values-can-be