# Excel/Access Percentiles Grouped By Name

Tags: sql, ms-access, excel-formula

I have a fairly large spreadsheet listing metals (parm_stored) and a numerical value (numvalue).  Each metal is already ranked smallest to largest by numerical value.  Each metal has at least 1000 rows of numerical values for a total of nearly 40,000 rows.

```
parm_stored numvalue
Aluminum    0.08
Aluminum    0.10
Aluminum    0.11
Aluminum    0.12
Antimony    0.12
Antimony    0.22
Antimony    0.29
Antimony    0.32
Antimony    0.35
Arsenic     0.17
Arsenic     0.19
Arsenic     0.20
Arsenic     0.22
Arsenic     0.25
```

Desired result:

```
parm_stored 99thPercentile
Aluminum    0.12
Antimony    0.35
Arsenic     0.25
```

I can get the percentile in Excel for a single metal, as well as in Access with an sql query.  The problem is that I can't get an accurate percentile for all the metals with one query or excel formula.  Access bogs down and won't even display percentile for all metals, but will give an inaccurate result if only working on a couple.

The following produces a correct result but is only querying a table (Aluminum) with one metal and 1150 rows.

```
SELECT Min(T1.numvalue) AS 99thPercentile
FROM Aluminum AS T1
WHERE ((((SELECT COUNT (*)
               FROM Aluminum As T2
               WHERE T2.numvalue <= T1.numvalue))>=((SELECT COUNT(*)
                   FROM Aluminum)*0.99)));
```

I tried adding the parm_stored row to the SELECT statement and GROUP BY T1.parm_stored to the end of the sql and with only two metals in the table, it would produce results, albeit inaccurate.

```
SELECT T1.parm_stored, Min(T1.numvalue) AS 99thPercentile
FROM TwoMetals AS T1
WHERE ((((SELECT COUNT (*)
               FROM TwoMetals As T2
               WHERE T2.numvalue <= T1.numvalue))>=((SELECT COUNT(*)
                   FROM TwoMetals)*0.99)))
GROUP BY T1.parm_stored;
```

Any suggestions/assistance?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quartile/Percentile in MS Access via SQL with a GROUP BY when some values can be NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30872060/quartile-percentile-in-ms-access-via-sql-with-a-group-by-when-some-values-can-be). Also review https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/DataAnalysis/percentiles/index.html

Comment: No, doesn't really help.  I have no null values so basically the where clauses would just get stripped out.  I already have the sql statement, but it isn't accurate.  I'm hoping that someone can look at what I've done and can help me fix it.  And I don't want to buy an additional piece of software if tweaking my sql is all that is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Code found at http://www.fabalou.com/Access/Modules/percentile.asp

Modified:

```
Public Function PercentileRst(strMetal As String, fldName As String, PercentileValue As Double) As Double
...
Set RstOrig = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT numvalue FROM Metals WHERE param_stored='" & strMetal & "'", dbOpenDynaset)
...
End Function
```

Called in query:

`SELECT DISTINCT param_stored, PercentileRst([param_stored],"[numvalue]",0.99) As Pctl FROM Metals;`

Output:

```
param_stored    Pctl  
Aluminum       0.1197  
Antimony       0.3488  
Arsenic        0.2488
```

Complete procedure with additional modifications removing MsgBox code and replace with returning 0 from function:

```
Public Function PercentileRst(strMetal As String, fldName As String, PercentileValue As Double) As Double

   Dim PercentileTemp As Double
   Dim dbs As Database
   Dim xVal As Double
   Dim iRec As Long
   Dim i As Long
   Dim RstOrig As Recordset
   Dim RstSorted As Recordset

   'This function will calculate the percentile of a recordset.
   'Field must be a number value and percentile has to be between 0 and 1.
   If PercentileValue < 0 Or PercentileValue > 1 Then
       PercentileRst = 0
   Else
       Set dbs = CurrentDb
       Set RstOrig = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT numvalue FROM Metals WHERE param_stored='" & strMetal & "'", dbOpenDynaset)
       RstOrig.Sort = fldName
       Set RstSorted = RstOrig.OpenRecordset()
       RstSorted.MoveLast
       RstSorted.MoveFirst
       xVal = ((RstSorted.recordCount - 1) * PercentileValue) + 1
       'x now contains the record number we are looking for.
       'Note x may not be whole number
       iRec = Int(xVal)
       xVal = xVal - iRec
       'i now contains first record to look at and
       'x contains diff to next record
       RstSorted.Move iRec - 1
       PercentileTemp = RstSorted(fldName)
       If xVal > 0 Then
          RstSorted.MoveNext
          PercentileTemp = ((RstSorted(fldName) - PercentileTemp) * xVal) + PercentileTemp
       End If
       RstSorted.Close
       RstOrig.Close
       Set RstSorted = Nothing
       Set RstOrig = Nothing
       Set dbs = Nothing
       PercentileRst = PercentileTemp
   End If
End Function
```